Can I refer table name in where clause in BigQuery?
I have this query:
SELECT
col_name_1,
col_name_2,
col_name_3
FROM table_catalog.table_schema.table_name_start*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'table_name_end'
but I got this error when I’m trying to run it:
Exception: Wildcard matched incompatible partitioning tables, first table table_catalog.table_schema.absolutely_other_table_name_1, first incompatible table table_catalog.table_schema.absolutely_other_table_name_2
I want to run this query in the loop and I have a list of all table_name_end values, but I can't write a whole name in from clause, I have to put it somewhere else. Is it event possible? These table_name_end are not numbers or dates.

Using wildcard with a dataset where there are mix partitioned tables (partitioned and non-partitioned) and if wildcard matches both types as output then it does not allow it.
